# @reboot jobs don't work

Tags: boot, cron

I have been trying to make my fedora pc do a little script at reboot but i can't get it to work.
My script works perfectly, for example if it's 02:10 and inside *crontab -e* I write **11 02 * * * /path/to/my/script**, then cron executes it flawlessly, but if I try to set it at boot time it simply doesn't work.

I already tried to use both my "normal" user and root user, but it doesn't help, it seems like cron doesn't like @reboot

Comment: What cron daemon? Not all support @reboot.

Comment: crontab... it shoul support it, right?

Comment: What does the script do? Perhaps some service or daemon that it relies on is not up/ready at that point in the boot sequence?

Comment: It's a simple ping...

"#!/bin/bash
/bin/ping 8.8.8.8"

Comment: So maybe networking is yet not up? what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

I thought that maybe as "@steeldriver" user said, the network couldn't have been ready yet when the system booted, hence I edited and added "sleep 120" before the command.
 Now it is "@reboot sleep 120; /path/to/my/script.sh > /home/myuser/itworks.txt 2>&1".

It simply works, it creates the file itworks.txt and if you "cat" it, you'll get all the info.

Answer (score 0):

You may invoke crontab as root,
 `crontab -e`
and then insert this line

`@reboot /home/myuser/bin/command.sh` 
where `command.sh` is the executable file  
**note:** chmod 755 command.sh